# How to convert string value separated by comma into integer from mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am working on a php project to retrieve data from mysql. I have a list of codes that is stored as a string separated by commas that is referenced in another table. Is there a way to get all the value from the string and return the text it referenced?

For example, item_purchased might contain one or more than one item_code. I want the query to return item names instead of item codes.

```
//item_purchased for transaction 123 --> ,111,222,333,

SELECT s.transaction_id, s.item_purchased, i.item_id
FROM stock s

INNER JOIN ref_item i
ON s.item_code = i.item_code

WHERE transaction_id = 123

Desired outcome: apple, carrot, milk (not ,111,222,333,)
```

Is there a way to do this preferably within mySQL query or maybe in PHP?

Comment: this is why you normalise the db, it would be simple if you did not use the comma separated list.

Comment: why cant you use explode() in php after fetching whole string from db

Comment: query for the list of names as well, turn the string in an array, you should be able to reference it like `$arr[$item_id]`

Comment: This is the proof for a very-bad database design. Cant you change this comma seperated list into a proper table structure? Its horrible!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the [reasons why you shouldn't use comma-separated lists in relational databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574#3653574).

The workaround is to use the [FIND_IN_SET() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) in the join conditions, instead of `=`.

```
SELECT s.transaction_id, GROUP_CONCAT(i.item_name)
FROM stock s

INNER JOIN ref_item i
ON FIND_IN_SET(i.item_code, s.item_purchased)

WHERE s.transaction_id = 123

GROUP BY s.transaction_id
```

But unfortunately, this makes the query very inefficient, because it can't use an index to search the ref_item table. It has to do a table-scan, so it ends up having very poor performance, and gets much worse the larger your table gets.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know it's possible to do this in mySQL. If performance is affected I might do the conversion in PHP first before calling the db.

Answer (score 0):

Is `item_purchased` a comma separated string of item_code?
I'm not good with joins but I think this will do

```
SELECT s.transaction_id, s.item_purchased, DISTINCT(i.item_id)
  FROM stock s, ref_item i
 WHERE i.item_code in (s.item_purchased ) 
   AND s.transaction_id = 123
```

This will return a list of all the items in the `item_purchased` column if my assumption of the item_purchase is right.

Comment: That's a syntax error. You can't use DISTINCT like it's a function.